# Find shared instance of AVPictureInPictureController to get isPictureInPictureActive value

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I used the following documentation to add the picture-in-picture feature to the standard player:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_standard_player

But now when the user navigates out of wrapper controller by this feature, I need to know about the status of the shared instance AVPictureInPictureController. I want to know if it's still active. In documentation there's an instance member related to that named `isPictureInPictureActive`:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller/1614720-ispictureinpictureactive

But the question is how can I get the shared instance of AVPictureInPictureController to be able to get the value of member `isPictureInPictureActive`?